# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in my_module_get_nodequeue_id_by_name() (line 30 of my_module/my_module.module)

Tags: 7

```
/**
 * Gets the nodequeue id by nodequeue name
 */
function my_module_get_nodequeue_id_by_name($name) {
  $data = db_query('SELECT qid FROM {nodequeue_queue} WHERE title = :title', array(':title' => $name))->fetchField();
  return $data->qid;
}
```

The above code produced this kind of notice:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in my_module_get_nodequeue_id_by_name() (line 30 of my_module/my_module.module).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`fetchField()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/DatabaseStatementInterface%3A%3AfetchField/7) returns a single value, not an object. You either want to use `fetchField()` like this:

```
$qid = db_query('SELECT qid FROM {nodequeue_queue} WHERE title = :title', array(':title' => $name))->fetchField();
return $qid;
```

or use [`fetchObject()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!prefetch.inc/function/DatabaseStatementPrefetch%3A%3AfetchObject/7) instead:

```
$data = db_query('SELECT qid FROM {nodequeue_queue} WHERE title = :title', array(':title' => $name))->fetchObject();
return $data->qid;
```